# Access factory function from nested class

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, nested, factory

What I have is:

• A **factory function**, with a *nested class* (so that it is more difficult to directly instantiate the class)

• Inside the class I have an *update* method which should **call the factory function to retrieve an updated version** of its instance

It is something like this:

```
def factory(someStr):
    #in my actual code I retrieve an updated value
    #for someStr from the internetz
    #I also have some other parameters, hence
    #the someInt parameter

    class NestedClass(object):
        def __init__(self, someStr, someInt):
            #... intialization code
            #someStr becomes a property here
            #(I omited that code)

        def update(self):
            return factory(self.someStr)

    return NestedClass(someStr, int(someStr))
```

It's the first thing I came up with and I kind of like the design (mainly its syntax is really short if I often update). On the downside I create lots of updated objects.

Unfortunately it gives me an error, which was what I expected ('dict not callable', because of the namespace of the nested class).

Is there any way to keep this design and call the function?

Comment: I... wouldn't keep this design.

Comment: Could you provide me with your thoughts? :-)

Comment: If you get `dict not callable` you have a naming conflict. The design, as posted here, works, but not if you *also* have a local name `factory` inside of your factory function that is a `dict`. When `update()` is called, `factory` is looked up either as a scoped name (from a parent function, so from the `factory()` locals) or as a global, with a nested scope name winning over a global name. You do have a `factory` global, but from your exception you evidently have a `factory` local *as well*. Post your real code so we can diagnose where.

Comment: Not without fully understanding what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Ok Ignacio: Lets say the factory gives me a Price object (the nested class) for an item I want to purchase. The price is retrieved from the internet and "saved" into the Price instance (together with a time, etc.). Whenever I want a new Price I call update on the instance. Does that clear things?

Comment: Martijn: Thank you for your comment. Actuall I have a class ‘Price' inside the factory function 'price'. Actually that shouldn't conflict should it? There are no other 'price' occurences in my code whatsoever. UPDATE: Ouch! I did have a local variable AFTER the class. But now it is complaining about a name clash with the 'Price' class. Is Python case-insensitive in this matter? I should read the docs.

Comment: @phikes: Then print `repr(price)` to diagnose what `price` is at the time you call `update()`. I fear you are overlooking something.

Comment: I accidently had a property decorator covering the update method. It works now. Thanks!

Comment: No gain in other readers here in reading this question (you were just having bugs), hence my downvote.